# ffmpeg dump specific length of video after seeking PICT_TYPE_I keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg, seek

I have a flv video and want to dump let's say `3s` length of the video after first keyframe `PICT_TYPE_I` meet after `00:39`. I ready the [document](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) of `ffmpeg seeking` and quote here

> `ffmpeg -ss 00:23:00 -i Mononoke.Hime.mkv -frames:v 1 out1.jpg`
>
> This example will produce one image frame (out1.jpg) at the
>   twenty-third minute from the beginning of the movie. The input will be
>   parsed using keyframes, which is very fast. As of FFmpeg 2.1, when
>   transcoding with ffmpeg (i.e. not just stream copying), -ss is now
>   also "frame-accurate" even when used as an input option. Previous
>   behavior (seeking only to the nearest preceding keyframe, even if not
>   precisely accurate) can be restored with the -noaccurate_seek option.

So I think if I use this command (put `-ss` before `-i`)

```
ffmpeg -noaccurate_seek -ss 00:39 -i input.flv  -r 10 -s 720x400 -t 3.12 dump.flv
```

And this should dump a video that last `3.12s` and begin with the first `keyframe` after `00:39` right? after all, this is what I need.

But the result is `dump.flv` not start with a `keyframe`, ie a `PICT_TYPE_I` frame.

I know I could find all `keyframe` start time with `ffprobe` and re-calculate the `-ss` seeking time to achieve this. But is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have audio as well?

Comment: no, audio is out of concern

Answer (score 0):

If audio is of no concern, you can use

```
ffmpeg -ss 39.00 -i in.flv -vf select='if(eq(pict_type,I),st(1,t),gt(t,ld(1)))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -an -t 3.12 out.flv
```

Here, the select filter discards all frames before the first keyframe which is after the seek point. The `t` value controls the total duration selected.

Do note that video duration is quantized i.e. a 25 fps video can have duration in steps of 0.04s.